# Confused on Config File

Tags: configuration, vim

Is there a standard editor to view config files in linux. I m just viewing the ls command (/bin) config file in vim editor but it shows my a lot of @ and alphabets. Can anyone tell me how to view any config file in linux. Whats i m doing wrong. 
Thanks

Comment: Not everything is a **configuration file**.  The `ls` command is a **compiled binary** and is not able to be read by any text or configuration editor.  You need to know the difference between binaries and editable files.

Comment: Didnt find any suitable tag.

Comment: See this thread. Use sudoedit
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408245&p=13828485#post13828485
Also how to change default editor

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a standard editor to view config files in linux.

vim

> I m just viewing the ls command (/bin) config file in vim editor but it shows my a lot of @ and alphabets.

Then those are NOT config files. Inside /bin there are (or should be) only binaries. Config files are in /etc/ and likely (or often have) have an extension ".conf"  or ".cnf" or are inside a "conf"  directory inside the projects base directory though that is up to the creator of software to decide.

---

```
locate .conf
locate .cnf
```

is going to yield lots of config files and directories that include config files.

Comment: How to view a binary file. And how identify a binary and config file.

Comment: binary file: with a hex editor. result will be hex code so you need to learn that too ;) and use the `file` command to see if a file is binary or text or something else. config files are text files (mosttimes)

Comment: Note that config files don't have to be plain text or binary only. The format is up to the developers to choose.